# What other uses are there for Prime numbers?

Tags: soft-question, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, cryptography, big-list

Simple question out of curiosity...

Beside the use of cryptographic safety and prime factorization, what other uses are there for prime numbers?

Thank you.

Edit: 
To clarify and not confusing with a possible 'duplicate' post. I'm asking for other uses than cryptographic-like applications. (this include cryptography (ex. RSA), hashes, pseudo random, etc.)
It doesn't necessary have to be something with engineering either. But knowing the innovative uses of primes in programs would be nice to know.

Another frequent answer is Cicadas, because they emerge every 13 or 17 years. For me that is something up for debate as it could also be just a coincidence.
I am comparing this example with petals, where you can see a repeated form of Fibonacci sequence with all different types of petals. All the while, doing some more research there are Cicadas that emerge every year as well.

I'm just curious as what else there is out there that could benefit from the use of primes.

Answer (score 1):

Would you accept an occurrence of prime numbers in nature giving a survival advantage? That is, would you accept the idea of evolution "using" prime numbers? If so, you should read about the prime life cycles of cicadas, e.g. [here](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-14305667). Probably not what you had in mind, but hey, a soft answer for a soft question.